# Solr. How to know which request handler is being used. While you are inside a search component

Tags: solr

I'm trying to make a solr plugin to report different statistics about solr queries, including things like number of results, what terms were used, and which core and request handler was used.

I thought of doing this as a custom SearchComponent, and adding it as a last component in all RequestHandlers, but I have one issue: I can't seem to find out which request handler is currently being used inside my search component. That is, in my plugin class that extends SearchComponent, how can I find the request handler?

I feel like this probably is probably easily accessible in some field and that I'm just blind. Any tips?

Edit:
One thing I could do is configure one search component for each request handler, where they each get some field with the request handler name/id. Although that isn't very pretty.

I also have a mild feeling my entire approach is wrong since I don't know Solr very well.

Comment: Initial thought - try to see if the [DebugComponent](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/8_0_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/handler/component/DebugComponent.html) includes the request handler - if so, it's [probably from resolving the stdinfo list](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/master/solr/core/src/java/org/apache/solr/handler/component/DebugComponent.java#L100). Second guess is to look under `req` on the ResponseBuilder and `getParams`.

Comment: Hmm, no luck there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can place within each request handler an attribute within the invariants (you could also place it within defaults-section, but since its an invariant, it makes sense to place it there) that names the handler and then access req.getParams to find that parameter (`handlerName`).

```
<requestHandler name="/myhandler" class="solr.SearchHandler">
        <lst name="invariants">
            <str name="handlerName">myhandler</str>
            .
            .
        </lst>
        .
        .
    </requestHandler>
```